# Excel Custom functions inside Excel Add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

I have a office add-in generated using Yeoman template for Taskpane type using Angular Framework. How do I add custom functions to this project and what changes do I have to make ?

I have already tried this using shared runtime and followed these instruction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime

I have created a custom function.ts file but those functions do not work in my add-in. I want to have an office add-in with some custom functions and Taskpane which would have other features. What am I missing here ?

This is the manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>a0198b78-0eee-4d33-88c2-0932fbd77d06</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Excel-CF"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long"/>
        </Runtimes>
        <AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
            <Script>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
            </Script>
            <Page>
              <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
            </Page>
            <Metadata>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
            </Metadata>
            <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </AllFormFactors>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/public/functions.js"/>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/public/functions.json"/>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Page.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="CII"/>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

This is the webpack.config.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin = require("custom-functions-metadata-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd = "https://www.contoso.com/"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { ca: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
      functions: "./src/functions/functions.ts",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "ts-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin({
        output: "functions.json",
        input: "./src/functions/functions.ts",
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane","functions"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "app.component.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/app/app.component.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "app.component"],
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

Comment: Can you share you manifest file so we could be sure all the required changes were made correctly? Did you also configure the webpack.config.js file? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Please find the files in this link: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TS3II_2mjIM_rhSDnmKaSsP8hoHb7CZd?usp=sharing

Comment: It makes sense to include them to the original post, so readers could find the cause easily.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have done that now.

Answer (score 1):

The [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) page describes all the required changes to make the add-in using the shared runtime and enable custom functions with full CORS support and task panes in the same add-in.

Be aware, when using a shared runtime, you can't use Visual Studio Code to debug custom functions in Excel on Windows at this time. You'll need to use developer tools instead.

Don't design your add-in to use multiple task panes if you are planning to use a shared runtime. A shared runtime only supports the use of one task pane. Note that any task pane without a `<TaskpaneID>` is considered a different task pane.

Comment: Above are the webpack config and manifest files. Do look at them and let me know if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Could you post them as a part of your question (not uploaded to the drive)?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev my workaround for multiple taskpanes + shared runtime is that all my Ribbon Buttons use `ExecuteFunction` and load HTML snippets into a `div` in the single `index.html` using `jquery`. Works really well! I think MSFT should put out a "All-In-One" template as trying to combine Custom Functions + Taskpanes + CommandFuncs was a nightmare to figure out. I've thought about releasing a scaffold on GitHub actually, but haven't got around to it as I'd have to spend time stripping/testing my current project.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers how did you manage to integrate the custom functions and the taskpane. Could you please send more info on this / document on this.